# What is difference between '&' and ',' in swift about Protocol Composition

Tags: ios, swift, class, protocols, composition

I have a question

In swift,

```
class Card : Equatable & CustomStringConvertible
```

and

```
class Card : Equatable, CustomStringConvertible
```

I think there are doing the same things.
What is different??

Comment: Think about how you would type an _instance property_ as being an adopter of both protocols. `let myVar : ???`

Comment: May look at this: https ://medium. com/@09mejohn/protocol-composition-in-swift-bd7ed6018ac5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Swift documentation on [protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html), I think `&` is mainly used when you are **requiring** a variable to adopt to multiple protocols, ex:

```swift
func wishHappyBirthday(to celebrator: Named & Aged) {
    print("Happy birthday, \(celebrator.name), you're \(celebrator.age)!")
}
```

And you use `,` when you want to **adopt** a custom struct/class to multiple protocols:

```swift
struct SomeStructure: FirstProtocol, AnotherProtocol {
    // structure definition goes here
}
```

Comment: Looks like `&` is a quick way to create *type alias* that represents a composition of protocols which is the only way to *require* an adoption of of multiple protocols for a var without creating such `typealias` explicitly. While the same syntax can be used for struct/class, perhaps you should opt to `,` when possible.

A side note: Swift lets us use the same syntax for class and subtype existentials, which means we can combine *protocols with classes* to be even more precise about what we accept. I.e.: `func showUserDetails(on vc: UserHandling & UIViewController)`.